# Asked to remove packages when trying to install with Muon?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu

I keep trying to install packages using Muon Discover on Kubuntu 13.10, but every time I try to install a package I get a message saying that there are other things installed that *have* to be removed.  Normally I wouldn't mind, but some of the things it claims have to be removed are things I am using (like kdeutils and kdegames).

Why do I have to remove these things?  I only want to install VLC Media player!  CAN I install this on Kubuntu?

Comment: Can you try going through `apt-get` in Konsole and see what it does? Muon has been good to me so far, but in Synaptic, it sometimes asked me to remove unrelated packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed VLC Media Player on every version of Kubuntu for ages now. That includes 10.04 through 13.10. Something is clearly wrong *somewhere*. VLC is not a KDE application and therefore has no KDE dependencies that would need to be removed. However there is not enough information in your post to provide an answer, such as what Kubuntu version and what KDE version for starters.

In Konsole (terminal) type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If there are errors in the results that will help you find out what is wrong and you can re-ask the question with the additional information.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it installed using sudo apt-get.  Darned if I know why it wouldn't work in Muon.  I am using Kubuntu 13.10 and I think it is the latest KDE.